# The Admin Dashboard Div

Tags: dashboard

How can I style and add new divs in the admin dashboard area inside of the wpbody div under the Dashboard Tab? I would like to insert a new div in the wpbody div...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_add_dashboard_widget` function:

```
wp_add_dashboard_widget($widget_id, $widget_name, $callback, $control_callback = null)
```

This Codex article should help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If something happens to that link this answer becomes useless. Your answer should be able to stand on its own.

Comment: Well. It's link to Codex. If this link disapears, then I don't think that this solution will work anymore either ;)